# Model view controller: shall the view know custom data types?

Tags: model-view-controller, custom-data-type

Very simple question: in a strict [MVC design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) we want to keep Model, View and Controller can the View layer know which custom data classes are defined in the model?

**As example**:

I got a CarViewController in the view layer and a Car object in the model layer. Whenever the model layer changes the controller object that "sits" **between the model and the view** notifies the CarViewController and in my current implementation passes a copy of the updated car data as an instance of the Car class. **Is this correct?**

My gut instinct would have **said no** because I would not want the view layer to know the details of the model objects. It is not strict decoupling. However if I pass specific values instead of passing the custom data model I would need to stick to standard/primitive values (E.g. int as number of wheels) and it may require more coding.

**Have I understood MVC correctly?** Is there any reason why the view should not know the custom classes of the model layer?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, I would say that your view needs to know the details of your Car object in most of the cases. You can utilize metadata in this way like this:

Model:

```
public class Car
{
    [Display(Name = "Number of wheels")]
    public int Wheels { get; set; }
}
```

View:
    @model Namespace.Models.Car

```
@* This will display whatever your [Display(Name="Value")] decorator defines
   as a display name, also the editor will respect the data type decorator. *@
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Wheels)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Wheels)
```

In this case if you basically pass down a primitive then all metadata for your model is lost.